# get subset dataframe by date

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following subset with a starting date (DD/MM/YYYY) and Amount

```
   Start Date    Amount
1  01/01/2013      20
2  02/05/2007      10
3  01/05/2004      15
4  01/06/2014      20
5  17/08/2008      21
```

I'd like to create a subset of this dataframe where only where the Start Date Day is 01:

```
   Start Date    Amount
1  01/01/2013      20
3  01/05/2004      15
4  01/06/2014      20
```

I've tried to loop through the table and use the index but couldn't find a suitable way to iterate through a dataframe rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your dates are datetime already then the following should work, if they are strings you can convert them using [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas.to_datetime) so `df['Start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Date'])`, you may also need to pass param `dayfirst = True` if required. If you imported the data using `read_csv` you could've done this at the point of import so `df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', parse_dates=[n], dayfirst=True)` where n is the index (0-based of course) so if it was the first then pass `parse_dates=[0]`.

One method could be to apply a lambda to the  column and use the boolean index returned this to index against:

```
In [19]:

df[df['Start Date'].apply(lambda x: x.day == 1)]
Out[19]:
       Start Date  Amount
index                   
1     2013-01-01      20
3     2004-05-01      15
4     2014-06-01      20
```

Not sure if there is a built in method that doesn't involve setting this to be the index which will convert it into a timeseries index.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. Start Date is Two words, and the data is string, not datetime , how can I cast string to datetime inside a lambda expression?

Comment: You can ignore the inconsistency in the column name, this was just the way I imported your data. You can and should convert strings to datetimes like so `df['Start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Date'])` you may need to pass param `dayfirst=True`, see the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas.to_datetime)